# How to use linq2db to insert sql geography?

Tags: c#, .net, linq2db

It is simple really:

```cs
var a = SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars("POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)"), 4326);`
```

and then insert

```cs
await _geoDb.Table.Value(x => x.Geom, a) // Geom is of type SqlGeography
```

This is giving me error:

> System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography to a known managed provider
> native type.

I tried manual insert with `geography::STGeomFromText` and that works as expected.

Mapping is:

```cs
[Column("geom"), Nullable] 
public SqlGeography Geom { get; set; } // geography
```

Table def.

```sql
create table municipal.country
(
    id       int identity
        constraint PK_Canton
            primary key,
    geom     geography
)
```

I am using for `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` this nuget `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.`

Linq2Db version is: 3.1.6 (if i update to latest it is a same thing).

**UPDATE**

I was able to resolve this by installing `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 1.5` and adding that custom assembly directive into Program.cs (https://linq2db.github.io/articles/FAQ.html#how-can-i-use-sql-server-spatial-types).

It is working for simple Point but in a case of multipolygon I am getting this error.

```c
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteBytes(ReadOnlySpan`1 b, Int32 len, Int32 offsetBuffer, Boolean canAccumulate, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Byte[] array)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteByteArray(Byte[] b, Int32 len, Int32 offsetBuffer, Boolean canAccumulate, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TDSExecuteRPCAddParameter(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlParameter param, MetaType mt, Byte options)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallback callback, Object stateObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsync(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endMethod, Object state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at LinqToDB.Data.RetryPolicy.RetryPolicyBase.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.QueryRunner.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.NonQueryQueryAsync(Query query, IDataContext dataContext, Expression expression, Object[] ps, Object[] preambles, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.NonQueryQueryAsync(Query query, IDataContext dataContext, Expression expression, Object[] ps, Object[] preambles, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.LinqToDB.Async.IQueryProviderAsync.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LinqToDB.LinqExtensions.InsertAsync[T](IValueInsertable`1 source, CancellationToken token)
   at GeoIndexer.Services.GeoIndexerService.IndexCantons(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/nikola/projects/immoledo/GeoIndexer/src/Geoindexer/Services/GeoIndexerService.cs:line 118
   at GeoIndexer.GeoIndexerConsoleApp.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<StartAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in /Users/nikola/projects/immoledo/GeoIndexer/src/Geoindexer/GeoIndexerConsoleApp.cs:line 41
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

**UPDATE**
It works, if i don't use `insertAsync` but just `InsertWithInt32Identity`

Comment: Please show your entity and mapping if any.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv as I said it is simple mapping.

Comment: Add column definition from database. Everything is needed to reproduce.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you mean table def?

Comment: Have you checked [How can I use SQL Server Spatial Types?](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/FAQ.html#how-can-i-use-sql-server-spatial-types) in the Linq2DB docs? Have you registered `SqlGeography` with `SqlServerTools.ResolveSqlTypes(typeof(SqlGeography).Assembly);` ?

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: .net core 3.1 and yes i did register.

Comment: i am using for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types this nuget dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.

Comment: Post that in the question. That's the most relevant part - the error says it didn't find the registered type. Which NuGet package did you use? `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` (wrong choice for .NET Core) or `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`? Which version of linq2db ?

Comment: @pregmatch, let me check. Will try to reproduce. I hope you have `await _geoDb.Table.Value(x => x.Geom, a).InsertAsync()`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i do have it :)

Comment: With `System.Data.SqlClient` use `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` 1.5, 
with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` use `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` 2.5

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i did that as well.

Comment: Which provider do you use? From two that I have mentioned above.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient -> dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Comment: Show your `csproj` file or better create small reproducible sample and post an issue in `linq2db` repository.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you check my update please.

Comment: If you need help. Post complete problem description. FULL call stack. And possible you have problem with `async/await` usage.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i added error message.

Comment: Well, probably something with `dotMorten`, try to change `DataProvider` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and update to `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 2.5`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you add answer so i can accept :)? like add dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 1.5 and use insert without async? you really helped me and i dont want you to go without extra points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which SQL Server provider do you use. `linq2db` supports both available ADO.NET Providers:

- For `System.Data.SqlClient` you have to use
  `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` `1.5`,
- For `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` use `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` `2.5`